# To use in struts config xml file the placeholders set in *.properties

Tags: java, struts2

I have a struts2 config file, and I have a problem setting URL depending on properties.

```
<action name="ABC" class="myAction" method="myMethod" >
            <result name="direct" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="namespace">/navigate</param>
                <param name="actionName">logout</param>
            </result>
            <result name="nonDirect" type="redirectAction">{url.set.in.properties}</result>
        </action>
```

Why do I need that - is because this URL could be different for diff environments (QA, UAT, prod, etc).

So is it possible to use property settings in struts config (like we use it in spring context files for example)?

Another problem - is the fact that URL should be global one, like 'www.google.com'. Currently it redirects to the wrong url "http://localhost/package_name_here/http://www.goggle.com"

Comment: what is the issue with current approach? you can create a constant in your `BaseAction` class and can use those values in `redirectAction` like ${property name}

Answer (score 0):

You can set in your `myAction` an attribute `myRedirect` with its getters and setters, set it with the property (with `getText(...)`) and then use it in the `struts.xml`.

**myAction**

```
class myAction extends ActionSupport {
    ...
    private String myRedirect; // TODO: Getters and setters
    ...
    public String execute () {
        ...
        myRedirect = getText('url.set.in.properties');
        ...
    }
}
```

And then in struts.xml you put a result with the type `redirect` to redirect to an absolute url:

**struts.xml**

```
...
<action name="ABC" class="myAction" method="myMethod" >
   <result type="redirect">
       <param name="location">${myRedirect}</param>
   </result>
</action>
...
```